# NGiNX Custom path of phpmyadmin

Tags: nginx, phpmyadmin

I am trying to change the directory of phpmyadmin which is working with single sign on from my main webroot. I have below configuration of my Vhost.

```
        listen 80 ;
        listen [::]:80 ;

        root /var/www/html;
        index index.php index.html index.htm ;
        server_name dewittborough.example.com;
       # add_header X-Robots-Tag "noindex, nofollow, nosnippet, noarchive";
        location / {
        include "/etc/nginx/custom_wp" ;
            try_files $uri $uri.php $uri/ /phpmyadmin;
    }
   include /etc/nginx/skip_cache.conf ;
   include /etc/nginx/gzip_location.conf ;
   include /etc/nginx/header.conf ;
    location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
    include "/etc/nginx/customfastcgi" ;
    proxy_connect_timeout 300;
    proxy_send_timeout 300;
    proxy_read_timeout 300;
    send_timeout 300;
    client_max_body_size 256M;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_main.conf ;
    }
    location = /phpmyadmin {
    root /var/www/;
}
}
```

if I  move the directory of phpmyadmin to /var/www/ i am getting 404 not found.
Sample signon URL is as follows
`https://dewittborough.example.com/phpmyadmin/sso.php?&remote_token=ikoblfqshqakinuiqd`

Comment: Check NGINX error and access logs, you should see the full path it tries to access. If that wouldn't give you a hint what to do - update your question with log records.

Comment: no error in error logs.
accesslogs are mentioned below.
```MYIP - - [31/Dec/2020:10:15:53 +0000] "GET /phpmyadmin/sso.php?container=dewittborough&remote_token=jxtjpaclarrkzntjiv HTTP/1.0" 404 139 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36" "myIP"```

Comment: How about [*not* installing phpMyAdmin](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/security/stop-installing-phpmyadmin)?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have PMA location declared with `=` sign. It means the location will fire **only** when you access `/phpmyadmin`. It won't trigger the location with `/phpmyadmin/sso.php` since it does not equal to `/phpmyadmin`. So first change the location to this:

```
location /phpmyadmin/ {
  ...
}
```

Next is your `root` directive. One thing about `root` is that it **concatenates** `root` and `location`. So with a config like this:

```
location /phpmyadmin/ {
  root /var/www;
}
```

NGINX will look for files in `/var/www/phpmyadmin/`. If you don't like this behaviour, swap `root` with `alias`:

```
location /phpmyadmin/ {
  alias /var/www/; # Beware of this trailing slash (/), it's mandatory.
}
```

With this configuration you will be able to access `index.php` and other files in `/var/www/` under `/phpmyadmin/`. Beware though that `/phpmyadmin/html/` will bring you to `/var/www/html/`.

Comment: issue still persists no error in logs.
```location  /phpmyadmin/ {
    alias /var/www/;
}```

Comment: @wajahat021 You may not see 404 in error log if you have `log_not_found off;` somewhere in config or maybe you are looking at the wrong file (error log is separate from access log). There should be a line like this: `[error] 6#6: *1 open() "/var/www/static/foo/bar" failed (2: No such file or directory)`.